# Formatting a date inside a user-defined function (mysql)

Tags: mysql, date, formatting, user-defined-functions

I have completed a school assignment but get extra credit if I format the date inside a user-defined function. Here is the working code:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS in_sentence_form;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION in_sentence_form (u_name TEXT, b_date DATE)
RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE full_sentence TEXT;
    SET full_sentence = CONCAT(u_name,' was born on ',b_date,'.');
    RETURN full_sentence;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

However, the output is simply "John Doe was born on 2001-01-01" (name on the left, date on the right); but what if I want the output to read: "John Doe was born on Wednesday, the 1st of January, 2001."?

I know how to format a date:

```
DATE_FORMAT(b_date, '%W %D %M %Y');
```

but inserting strings and characters in between the specifiers like "the", "of", "," are proving to be impossible.

An online search is not working as my search words would have to be nearly exact to the date strings others have used

Comment: I have figured out the syntax for mixing characters and words in between the date elements:

    SELECT CONCAT('Jaron Jones was born on ', DATE_FORMAT('2001-05-01','%W'), ", the", DATE_FORMAT('2001-05-01','%D'), " day of ", DATE_FORMAT('2001-05-01','%M'), ", ",DATE_FORMAT('2001-05-01','%Y'),".") AS Birthdate;

but now I just need to get all of that inside the user-defined function!

Comment: Figured it out. This is the SET line:

SET full_sentence = CONCAT(u_name,' was born on ', DATE_FORMAT(b_date,'%W'), ", the ", DATE_FORMAT(b_date,'%D'), " day of ", DATE_FORMAT(b_date,'%M'), ", ", DATE_FORMAT(b_date,'%Y'),".");

Comment: Note that what you have written here is a *stored* function, **not** a *user-defined* function.  User-defined functions (UDF) are written in C or C++, not SQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-udf.html

Answer (score 0):

You can insert literals in the format string.

```
date_format(b_date, '%W, the %D of %M, %Y')
```

E.g.:

```
SELECT date_format(now(), '%W, the %D of %M, %Y');
```

will result in

```
Saturday, the 6th of April, 2019
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4694fa79ba1e889f4c9bead527024d8a)